# React svg / png render is flickering on new URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using latest `create-react-app` config and facing the issues when switching between different routes.

All my `SVG`'s are included in sprite file. Logically, **sprite.svg** file should be cached on the first-page load.

But instead, every change of route (with `react-router` 4) loads this file which causes flickering. Content changes instantly, but images loads with 1s lag.
Same for `png` included via `import` in `jsx`.

From what I cant see in the console, same files download over and over again.

Live demo at http://cabin.surge.sh/ (i.e. try to change between Pricing / About pages in the header section)

[image]

**Update:**

The way I include SVG image - is dumb component `<SvgIcon name="checkmark" />`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import sprite from '../images/sprite.svg';

export default class SvgIcon extends Component {
  render(){
    const { name } = this.props;
    return(
      <svg className={"ico ico-" + name}>
        <use xlinkHref={sprite + "#ico-" + name}></use>
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

PNG images

```
<img src={require(`../images/${authorImage}.png`)} srcSet={require(`../images/${authorImage}@2x.png`)  + ' 2x'} alt=""/>
```

Comment: Add the code where you import these images and how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get a `200` instead of `304` is that you have a service worker which will intercept the request and serve the same from the cache itself. Which itself is `200` response. If you disable the service worker then you will get a `304`

[image: Service worker returning 200]

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that the image is not fetched earlier and causing flickering on page change, try to use

```
componentDidMount() {
  const sprite = "../images/sprite.svg";
  const prefetchLink = document.createElement("link");

  prefetchLink.href = sprite;
  prefetchLink.rel = "prefetch";
  prefetchLink.as = "image";
  document.body.appendChild(prefetchLink);
}
```

This will hint the browser to fetch resources in the background (idle time) that might be needed later, and store them in the browser’s cache. Once a page has finished loading it begins downloading additional resources and if a user then clicks on a prefetched link, it will load the content instantly.

For a functional version:

```
//custom hook to preload image
const usePreload = (url) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const onLoad = React.useCallback(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const prefetchLink = document.createElement('link');
    prefetchLink.href = url;
    prefetchLink.rel = 'prefetch';
    prefetchLink.as = 'image';
    prefetchLink.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    document.body.appendChild(prefetchLink);
    //clean up
    return () => document.body.removeChild(prefetchLink);
  }, [onLoad, url]);
  return loaded;
};

export default function SvgIcon({ name }) {
  const url = sprite + '#ico-' + name;
  const loaded = usePreload(url);
  return (
    loaded && ( //only render if image is loaded
      <svg className={'ico ico-' + name}>
        <use xlinkHref={url}></use>
      </svg>
    )
  );
}
```

Note that if you do server side rendering you don't want this code to execute on the server because there is no `document` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a cache TTL max-age to something like `600` for example. This means you want the asset to be cached for 10 minutes.

[image: Cache Control]

If you are using NextJS you can add this to your `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:all*(svg)',
        locale: false,
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'public, max-age=600, must-revalidate',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```