# Passing props to class components, invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

In a function component I can do something along the lines of

```
function TestComponent(input) {
   const testa = input.a;
   const testb = input.b;
   return (
      <>
         <h1>{testa}</h1>
         <h2>{testb}</h2>
      </>
   );
} 

TestComponent.propTypes = {
   a: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   b: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

for some input of the form

```
const input = {
   a: something,
   b: somethingelse
};
```

following the documentation of converting to class components, and replacing this.props

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     const testa = this.props.input.a;
     const testb = this.props.input.b;
     return (
        <>
           <h1>{testa}</h1>
           <h2>{testb}</h2>
        </>
     );
   }
} 

TestComponent.propTypes = {
   a: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   b: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

but seem to be getting an invalid hook call. Looked through https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html but not sure why this would be considered a hook or how I'd go about passing input to a class component?

**UPDATE**

Your question was closed (I thought it wasn't good since you didn't demonstrate code that produces the behaviour you describe). But your comment shows what you actually want to do.

You can apply the solution form [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934208/1641941) in functional components:

```
//custom hook to preload image
const usePreload = (url) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const onLoad = React.useCallback(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const prefetchLink = document.createElement('link');
    prefetchLink.href = url;
    prefetchLink.rel = 'prefetch';
    prefetchLink.as = 'image';
    prefetchLink.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    document.body.appendChild(prefetchLink);
    //clean up
    return () => document.body.removeChild(prefetchLink);
  }, [onLoad, url]);
  return loaded;
};

export default function SvgIcon({ name }) {
  const url = sprite + '#ico-' + name;
  const loaded = usePreload(url);
  return (
    loaded && ( //only render if image is loaded
      <svg className={'ico ico-' + name}>
        <use xlinkHref={url}></use>
      </svg>
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: ah sorry, meant to put in render, I'm trying to use the componentDidMount solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659679/react-svg-png-render-is-flickering-on-new-url to fix flickering svg sprites

Comment: I put the answer in your question. It was closed because as you posted the question it wasn't very useful.